# How can I avoid circular imports in Python Google App Engine Ndb (pattern to avoid)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, python-import, app-engine-ndb

I am trying find pattern avoiding circular import in Python Google App Engine Ndb datastore architecture. I want to have **separate files** which parent mode and children models (related to parent).

Only option which I found is to join parent and children into one file but it make code too complicated and not easy to scale (add more lines).

Currently I have such project structure.

```
parent.py - parent entity
base.py - abstract base entity for children
children.py - children module
```

I was read this answer [How to avoid circular imports in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7336802/how-to-avoid-circular-imports-in-python) and trying to use but without success it is O.K. with typical Python **objects** but not works with initialized **ndb properties**. I spend some hours but has no idea why it is not works.

**parent.py** *(need children for delete dependencies)*

```
import children
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

class Parent(ndb.Model):
  def deleteWithChildren(self):
    for child in children.Child.query(Child.parent == self.key).fetch():
      child.key.delete()
    self.key.delete()
```

**base.py** *(need parent for Reference)*

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
import parent

class BaseChild(ndb.Model):
  parent = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=parent.Parent)
```

**children.py** *(need base do need Parent too)*

```
import base

class Child(base.BaseChild):
  pass
```

It produce exception when I try to execute such code `import Parent`:

```
  File "sandbox\sandbox.py", line 6, in <module>
    from web_site.seo.frontend.sandbox.parent import Parent
  File "sandbox\parent.py", line 4, in <module>
    import children
  File "sandbox\children.py", line 4, in <module>
    import base
  File "sandbox\base.py", line 7, in <module>
    class BaseChild(ndb.Model):
  File "sandbox\base.py", line 8, in BaseChild
    parent = ndb.KeyProperty(model=parent.Parent)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Parent'
```

Comment: was this ever resolved? I'm having the exact same issue

Answer (score 3):

You can replace the query requiring `parent` to import `children`, namely

```
children.Child.query(Child.parent == self.key)
```

with a `GQL` query, which is happy with just strings:

```
ndb.gql('SELECT * FROM Child WHERE parent = :1').bind(self.key)
```