# collection_name for ndb.KeyProperty

Tags: google-app-engine

`db.ReferenceProperty` allowed for a `collection_name` argument that specified how the reference object R could query for the objects that contain R as a reference.

I don't see a similar argument for [`ndb.KeyProperty`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/entity-property-reference#types). How do folks get around that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took a little getting used to when I made the switch to `ndb`, but it is actually simpler.  The `collection_name` is just syntactic sugar for a query, and you can do the query yourself:

```
MyEntity(ndb.Model):
    a_key = ndb.KeyProperty()

entities = MyEntity.query(MyEntity.a_key == some_key)
```

Below you can see a [fuller example from this Google group](https://groups.google.com/g/google-appengine/c/HZdFNh66xsQ) which creates a new `@property` on the referenced class (the "one";; the Post in this case) instead of on the referencing class (the "many"; the Comment in this case):

**OLD** db:

```
class Post(db.Model):
    content = db.TextProperty(required = True)   
   
class Comment(db.Model):
    """ Comment object with many-to-one relationship """
    content = db.TextProperty(required = True) 
    post = db.ReferenceProperty(Post, collection_name='comment_set')
```

**NEW** ndb:

```
class Post(ndb.Model):
    content = ndb.TextProperty(required = True)   

    @property
    def comment_set(self):
        return Comment.query(Comment.post == self.key)

class Comment(ndb.Model):
    """ Comment object with many-to-one relationship """
    content = ndb.TextProperty(required = True) 
    post = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=Post)
```

If your Model classes are in separate files, you might need to change the approach to [avoid circular imports](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31867625/1175496)

You could use a GQL Query String in the `@property`:

```
    @property
    def comment_set(self):
        return ndb.gql('SELECT * FROM Comment WHERE post = :1').bind(self.key)
```

Or you could use the [string `'Post'` for the `kind` argument](https://googleapis.dev/python/python-ndb/latest/model.html#google.cloud.ndb.model.KeyProperty), instead of the class `Post`, to avoid circular imports:

```
    post = ndb.KeyProperty(kind='Post')
```