# Import vs import on circular import?

Tags: python, python-2.7, import

I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7336802/how-to-avoid-circular-imports-in-python/37126790#37126790) about how to prevent circular import in python. I don't understand a claim in the post:

```
import package.a # Absolute import and 
import a # Implicit relative import (deprecated, py2 only)
```

can avoid circular import but

```
from ... import ...
#or
import ... as ..
```

can't (on python 2.x).

Does anyone know the reason behind this?

Answer (score 0):

After some search, I figure out the answer myself.

Essentially, circular import is a problem for `from … import …` because it returns the imported module only after the module code is executed.

To illustrate, assume we have import a in b.py and import b in a.py. For `import a` and `import b`, I simply look up sys.modules to find a/b, just put a new module in and return.

On the other hand, `from a import c` in b.py has code like this (pseudo python, similar for `from b import d` in a.py)

```
if 'a' not in sys.modules:
    sys.modules[a] = (A new empty module object)
    run every line of code in a.py
    add the module a to its parent's namespace
return module 'a'
```

we start from a.py, put an empty module for b to sys.modules and start executing b.py and put a in sys.modules and executing a.py. Next it hits `from b import d` again and find the b in sys.modules but it's empty, throws error: no attribute d.

PS1: the referred post is wrong. `import ... as ...` is good for circular import.

PS2: `from a import c` is the same to import a.c in python 3