# Python class instance circular referencing in different files using 'IMPORT AS'

Tags: python, python-import, importerror, circular-dependency, circular-reference

I am encountering a problem using a circular importation in Python 2.7

For some reasons, I need this structure, here reduced for the explanation to 4 python files :

```
- main.py
- folder
  \- __init__.py
  \- loader.py
  \- folder1
     \- __init__.py
     \- class1.py
  \- folder2
     \- __init__.py
     \- class2.py
```

main.py :

```
import folder.loader as LD

LD.a.change_class2()
LD.b.change_class1()
```

loader.py :

```
from folder1.class1 import Class1
from folder2.class2 import Class2

a=Class1()
b=Class2()
```

class1.py :

```
import folder.loader as LD

class Class1():
    def __init__(self):
        self.pty1=0
    def change_class2(self):
        LD.b.pty2=2
```

class2.py :

```
import folder.loader as LD

class Class2():
    def __init__(self):
        self.pty2=0
    def change_class1(self):
        LD.a.pty1=6
```

The code executed is `main.py`. This script calls the file `loader.py` which creates an instance for Class1 and Class2. The instances have to communicate and modify each other, explaining the necessity (if I am not wrong) of the file `loader.py`.

Executing this code returns the error from `class1.py` :

```
    import folder.loader as LD
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'loader'
```

I have no idea of what is going on here.

Surprisingly, when I remove the part `as LD` from the importation command line in the classes files, it works perfecly :

class1.py :

```
import folder.loader

class Class1():
    def __init__(self):
        self.pty1=0
    def change_class2(self):
        folder.loader.b.pty2=2
```

class2.py :

```
import folder.loader

class Class2():
    def __init__(self):
        self.pty2=0
    def change_class1(self):
        folder.loader.a.pty1=6
```

For this example, it's ok, but in the real program I am trying to make, based on this structure, I can't use the complete module path each time I need to communicate with another class instance.

Why am I getting this error ? What can I do to solve this ?
Thank you in advance for your help.

---

EDIT : replacing `import folder.loader as LD` by `from .. import loader as LD` now returns another error, that I don't understand :

```
    from .. import loader as LD
ImportError: cannot import name loader
```

Comment: "I am encountering a problem using a circular importation" - okay, obvious first suggestion, don't use circular imports. You think that you "need this structure", but it's highly likely you can change things to not require circular imports.

Comment: possibly helpful: [How to avoid circular imports in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7336802/how-to-avoid-circular-imports-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem simply by using Python 3, without code changes.