# Importing from views to models in Django

Tags: python, django, python-import, circular-dependency

I have something like this in one of my apps's `models.py` :

```
class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
```

I want to import a class from another app's views.py as below:

```
from anotherapp.views import MyClass
```

The problem is in the first lines of `anotherapp.views` file, I imported the `Account` class. So when I want to import `MyClass` into my `models.py` file, this error raises :

```
ImportError: cannot import name Account
```

Comment: It is a circular import error. Models shouldn't import from views as it is a bad practice. Why would you need MyClass in models? If you still need to, you can put MyClass into some other file, say `utils.py`, then let views and models import from that one.

Comment: @hurturk should I put `utils.py` in anotherapp folder or in my current app ? Does it matters at all ?

Comment: In `anotherapp`, but it doesn't matter as long as it doesn't break your project, you would need to rearrange all imports for `MyClass` depending on the location.

Answer (score 2):

That is circular import error you are encountering. While it is [bad practice](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/misc/design-philosophies/#loose-coupling) to import from views to models in Django, if you still want to, you can follow methods in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7336802/1233686) to resolve it.

Here are few alternative ways that can be considered as good practice:

- You can consider importing other low-level modules exist within `anotherapp` instead of `MyClass` (not depending on `views.py`)
- You can use Django's [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/signals/) to catch `anotherapp`'s events project wide and act according to.
- You can create a third file, say `utils.py` in `anotherapp`, move `MyClass` there and let `anotherapp/views.py` and your app's `models.py` import from `anotherapp.utils`