# How to import properly from the nested folder above?

Tags: python-3.x, relative-path

I have the following structure:

```
/a
 /b
  module1.py
/c
  module2.py
```

So, from some root folder there are 2 modules:

a/b/module1.py and

c/module2.py

I want to do import of some function of module1 from module2.

All 3 folders have ____init___.py

Both py files have inside:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    func()
```

module2.py has the following import code:

```
from .. a.b.module1 import func1
```

If I just run module2.py from a terminal (staying in the root folder):

```
python -m c.module2.py
```

I have the following error:

```
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common problem with the python import system, but one way to make it more manageable may be to define some imports in another `__init__.py` in your projects root directory, which will create a separate namespace for your package and all subdirectories.

The way I setup the directories to reproduce your error is this structure:

Root directory: `/package`:

```
/package
/package/__init__.py
/package/a
/package/a/__init__.py
/package/a/b
/package/a/b/__init__.py
/package/a/b/module1.py
/package/c
/package/c/__init__.py
/package/c/module2.py
```

In `package/__init__.py` put the top-level module imports:

```
from a.b import module1
```

and then the only change I made is to `module2.py` to contain only this function for testing:

```
from package import a # import top-level module from root package 

def func():
    a.b.module1.some_object() # call function of module1 from module2 (this module).

if __name__ == '__main__':
    func()
```

then in the top-level root of the package, from terminal you should be able to run `module2.py`:

```
$ python package/c/module2.py
```

should print out:

```
from a.b.module1: some object
```

Improvement and refinements can be made to get the exact behavior you desire.

For reference, I used this answer's suggestions: [How to avoid circular imports in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37126790/1248974)

Comment: Why is it sooooo complicated? Python pretends to be a simple language, but turns out to be a nightmare as soon as you do one small step aside :(