# Calling function without import the other file function in same directory

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I want to call im1.py's want_to_call() method from im2.py Test's class func1() and func1() will be called by im1's some_func() method....
Your help will be appreciated.

## im1.py

```
from im2 import Test

def some_func(value):
    Test.func1()
    print(value)


def want_to_call():
    return 'called from im2'

some_func("ola")
```

## im2.py

```
from im1 import want_to_call

class Test:
    def func1():
        variable = want_to_call()
        print(variable)
        print('How do I call want_to_call method in im1')


class Test1:
    def func():
        print('Thanks in advance')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid circular imports in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7336802/how-to-avoid-circular-imports-in-python)

Comment: @ruddra thanx sir, can u please do it with my question, I'll be thankful for that.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't do that.

The advice to "only import the module" works ([How to avoid circular imports in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7336802/how-to-avoid-circular-imports-in-python#answer-7336880)).
But you'd be better off putting your functions into more files that are arranged in a hierarchy.
In other words, **break the cycle**.
It will be beneficial for the organization of your code,
and of your unit tests,
and for how *you* think about your high level problem.

Here, the definitions of `want_to_call()` and `func1()` belong in additional files, which both im1 & im2 `import`.

Tests should depend upon target code, not the other way around.

Comment: your answer is good but I am doing this in django like one is views.py and 2nd file is some services.py, so I want to do that thing only in views.py.      And Second thing, importing a file instead of function may create performance problem because I have so  many functions and so many things in views.py, by the way your answer is also very helpful thanks

Comment: Even for views & services, you still have an opportunity to evict common functions into some utility.py file. As far as elapsed time goes, the `import` happens just once when django starts up. Your code is small, relative to the other libraries you are importing, so absent timing results I wouldn't worry much about such overheads, they're not the dominant source of delay.

Comment: but I tried that code which is given in answer, it is not working or I'm doing this wrong can u please check it once according to their answer