# How does cross importing modules work in python?

Tags: python, import, module

I am new to Python. I was playing with "Importing modules" in python and came to this 'thing' :

This is my `main.py`

```
import test

test.hello()
```

This is my `test.py`

```
import main

def hello():
    print("hello")
```

It results in

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import test
  File "/home/imtiazirtiaz/Desktop/Python/test/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import main
  File "/home/imtiazirtiaz/Desktop/Python/test/main.py", line 3, in <module>
    test.hello()
AttributeError: module 'test' has no attribute 'hello'
```

So I thought the function was not defined. So I changed the `test.py`

```
def hello():
    print("hello")

import main
```

But now when I run `main.py`, the output is:

```
hello
hello
```

Why does it prints `hello` twice?

And running the `test.py` says:

```
hello
```

Please help me showing what is going on. How does cross importing modules work in python?

I am using python 3.6

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7336802/how-to-avoid-circular-imports-in-python, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22187279/python-circular-importing, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744373/circular-or-cyclic-imports-in-python

Answer (score 1):

you are getting `hello` twice because in `test.py` file you have imported `main.py` file which contain a `import` statement and a function call to the `hello()`

remove `import main` from `test.py` every thing will work fine.

Comment: by what u mean 'fine'? I did not mention a 'problem'. I wanted to know why this was happening.If your answer is - "don't import module like this" - then how does it answer the question named - "How does cross importing modules work in python"?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to get rid of the line `import main` in `test.py`. Here's why:

In the first instance you have:

1. Run `main.py`
2. The first step is to import `test`.
3. Now Python is told to import `main` again.
4. Since we're already in the process of `import test`, the next step is `test.hello()`
5. But `def hello(): ...` has not yet been evaluated, so there's an error.

---

In the second case you have:

1. Run `main.py`
2. Import `test`
3. Now we define `hello()` so `test.hello` evaluates to the `hello()` function.
4. Import `main` again
5. We've already imported `test`
6. So now run `test.hello()` which is the `hello()` function.
7. Now we've finally finished the first import of `test` from step 2.
8. Finally run `test.hello()`

So `test.hello()` runs twice.

---

You're touching here on the issue of circular dependencies. For now my advice is not to import anything you don't need, and don't execute anything at the top-level of a file of package.

Best practice if you want a file to run is to do it like this:

**main.py**

```
import test

def main():
    test.hello()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # what to do if the file is called 
    main()
```

This way, if you later want to call the main function but not as a file, it is very easy to do so...

```
import main
main.main()
```