# How to connect logic and GUI files (Python3, Tkinter)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, import

I faced a problem connected with **import** in Python. I've implemented a simple calculator, there is no much code but I'd like to separate my logic from GUI (implemented with Tkinter).

My logic file *calc_logic.py*:

```
import enum
from calculator import*
....
```

My GUI file *calculator.py*:

```
from tkinter import *
from calc_logic import *
...
```

I get an Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/vladsokolovskii/Desktop/python/gui_project/calculator.py", line 4, in <module>
    from calc_logic import *
  File "/Users/vladsokolovskii/Desktop/python/gui_project/calc_logic.py", line 2, in <module>
    from calculator import *
  File "/Users/vladsokolovskii/Desktop/python/gui_project/calculator.py", line 25, in <module>
    clear_button = Button(win, text = 'C', padx = 20, pady = 15, command = button_clear)
NameError: name 'button_clear' is not defined
```

Definition of **button_clear()** in *calc_logic.py*:

```
...
def button_clear():
        display.delete(0, END)
        display.insert(0, '0')
...
```

The first reference to **button_clear()** in *calculatro.py*

```
...
clear_button = Button(win, text = 'C', padx = 20, pady = 15, command = button_clear)
...
```

**I tried:**

```
clear_button = Button(win, text = 'C', padx = 20, pady = 15, command = lambda: button_clear())
```

It didn't give me the Error nor worked -_-

I tried to change my code in different ways but never succeed.

Could you please explain to me where the problem is, I'm new to Python and I can't find a similar problem on the Internet, I'm sure that there is a solution but I just don't know how to google it correctly...

Thanks!

Comment: When `calculator` is being imported in `calc_logic.py`, `button_clear()` function is not defined yet.  Try refactoring your code not importing `calculator` in `calc_logic.py`.

Comment: This is a cyclic import. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7336802/how-to-avoid-circular-imports-in-python to solve this problem