# Issue with a dictionary duplicating itself

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, when I execute the code it print two different dictionaries, with similar objects (but different probably since the object index is different). Here is both scripts. Ignore everything in both scripts apart from init constructor, Ability.add_ability(), and Entity.learn_abilities().
I have thought of posting the entire scripts for better overview, at the bottom of Ability.py there are some statements I have made for testing, which results in two dictionaries, called learned_abilities which have similar but differently indexed objects. The problem is that I only need one.
Thanks in advance to anyone! I am a beginner!
Ability.py:

```
from Entity import *
class Ability():
    def __init__(self, ability_attributes):
        self.ability_attributes = ability_attributes

    def set_ability(self):
        self.name = self.ability_attributes[0]
        self.type = self.ability_attributes[1]
        self.element = self.ability_attributes[2]
        self.power = self.ability_attributes[3]
        self.description = self.ability_attributes[4]

    def execute_ability(self, owner, opponent):
        if self.type == "Black":
            if self.element == "Fire":
                total_damage = (self.power * owner.mag) / opponent.fireres
            elif self.element == "Ice":
                total_damage = (self.power * owner.mag) / opponent.iceres
            elif self.element == "Lightning":
                total_damage = (self.power * owner.mag) / opponent.lightres
            elif self.element == "Wind":
                total_damage = (self.power * owner.mag) / opponent.windres
            elif self.element == "Physical":
                total_damage = (self.power * owner.mag) / opponent.magres
            opponent.hp -= total_damage
        if self.type == "White":
            if self.name == "Cure" or self.name == "Cura" or self.name == "Curaga":
                total_healed = self.power * owner.spirit
            opponent.hp += total_healed
        if self.type == "Support":
            if self.name == "Haste":
                opponent.speed *= 2
            if self.name == "Slow":
                opponent.speed /= 2
            if self.name == "Protect":
                opponent.dif *= 1.5
            if self.name == "Might":
                opponent.atk *= 1.5
            if self.name == "Shell":
                opponent.fireres *= 2
                opponent.iceres *= 2
                opponent.lightres *= 2
                opponent.windres *= 2
                opponent.magres *= 2

    def add_ability(self, learner):
        learner.learn_abilities(self)

fire = ["Fire", "Black", "Fire", 90, "Strike with small fire damage."]
blizzard = ["Blizzard", "Black", "Ice", 90, "Strike with small ice damage."]
thunder = ["Thunder", "Black", "Lightning", 90, "Strike with small lightning damage"]
cure = ["Cure", "White", None, 90, "Restore a small amount of hp."]
haste = ["Haste", "Support", None, 0, "Double target speed."]

player_stats = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,]
player = Entity(player_stats)
Fire = Ability(fire)
Fire.set_ability()
Fire.add_ability(player)
Blizzard = Ability(blizzard)
Blizzard.set_ability()
Blizzard.add_ability(player)
print(player.learned_abilities)
```

Entity.py:

```
class Entity():
    def __init__(self, stats):
        self.stats = stats
        self.learned_abilities = {}

    def setting_stats(self):
        self.hp = self.stats[0]
        self.atk = self.stats[1]
        self.dif = self.stats[2]
        self.speed = self.stats[3]
        self.mag = self.stats[4]
        self.fireres = self.stats[5]
        self.iceres = self.stats[6]
        self.lightres = self.stats[7]
        self.windres = self.stats[8]
        self.magres = self.stats[9]
        self.spirit = self.stats[10]

    def learn_abilities(self, new_ability):
        self.learned_abilities[new_ability.name] = new_ability

    def battle_input(self):
        player_input = """
        1. Attack     2. Defend
        3. Black Magics   4.White Magics
        5. Support Magics"""


from Ability import *
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You have not written what are "the error mentioned" ;-)

Comment: It isn't technically an error, as I said, it creates two dictionaries called learned_abilities. Anyway, edited so it can be more understandable.

Comment: In Entitiy.py: `from Ability import *` and in Ability.py: `from Entity import *` you can't do this as it leads to a circular import

Comment: But are you saying you're getting 2 dictionaries in one instance of the `Entity` class?

Comment: Where is the test script where you see these 2 dictionaries

Comment: At the end of Ability.py i create all needed instances and proceed to print the dictionary, the result of printing is 2 different dictionaries, each One has two keys "Fire" and "Blizzard" but different object indexes.

Comment: `{'Fire': <__main__.Ability object at 0x000001DABC5A3808>, 'Blizzard': <__main__.Ability object at 0x000001DABC5A3848>}` this is what I get from running your code, it is one dictionary with 2 key: value pairs

Comment: Regarding the circular import, I get what that means and basically I had to import Ability at the end because if not there would be missing definition. I couldnt figure of a better way to solve that problem.

Comment: What do you mean, I don't think importing ability is necessary

Comment: Could you show the 2 dictionaries you're getting?

Comment: @Rolv Apneseth Then something strange happens because I get one as you say and another which basically says: {'Fire': <ability.Ability object...>, 'Blizzard': <ability.Ability object...>}

Comment: Oh my God I am stupid! The problem Is probably that import. I don't know why but It seems the most probable option

Comment: Yeah you shouldn't have the circular import I removed it on my test

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I couldnt believe it was such a stupid error! This program is by far the most complicated thing I tried yet, can't believe the only bug is something like this.

Comment: Glad to help man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be solved in the comments but I'll leave an answer here in case someone else comes looking. You might want to have a look at the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7336802/14316282) to see how to avoid circular imports.

Basically though, for your current code, removing the following line from Entity.py seems to have fixed the issue, as the problem was being caused by circular imports:

```
from Ability import *
```

Comment: I'd like to mention the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports) concerning the wildcard import: "Wildcard imports (`from <module> import *`) should be avoided, as they make it unclear which names are present in the namespace, confusing both readers and many automated tools."

Comment: I agree ideally always try to avoid wildcard imports