# Problem importing a module from a local package containing some modules that are used in other modules in the same package

Tags: python

Within a folder `somedir` I have several directories `dir1`, `dir2` etc. and some files `x.py`, `y.py`, `z.py` etc. In `dir1` there are modules `a`, `b`, `c` etc., module `a` is used in module `b` (like `from a import somethings`) with no problem as usual.

But when I try to use any module say, `a` within module `x` and use this module `x` within module `z`, error occurs.

```
somedir/
    |dir1/
    |   |__init__.py
    |   |a.py
    |   |b.py # from a import somethings / import a etc. -> ok
    |   |c.py
    |dir2/...
    |.
    |.
    |.
    |x.py # from dir1.a import * or somethings -> error (`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named a`)
    |y.py
    |z.py # from x import * or somethings -> error (`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named a`)
```

I haven't created any packages neither want to, as I want to use this in an application program. Should I really make a package for this to work. How can I manage such imports.
Please help.

Comment: Why don't you want to create packages?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid circular imports in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7336802/how-to-avoid-circular-imports-in-python)

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Ok, I should be more specific, I will update the post soon.

Comment: @Mihai no, this is not the case here.

Comment: Have you read through the answers on that question and determined they don't solve your problem? What have you tried? Looks like you are only using the `from x import y` syntax, which answers on that question suggest may cause the problem you're experiencing. There's at least 4 different solutions proposed there, so without mentioning which ones you've tried it's very difficult to see this very generic question as anything more than a duplicate.

Comment: @Mihai, let's consider this case, I have a central module in `dir1` which I will be using in other modules in the same directory `dir1` to avoid any circular import. But whenever I try to import any module from `dir1` within any one of `x`, `y` or `z` etc. in any way, the problem occurs (says, `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named, say, a).

Comment: You may also want to look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43728431/relative-imports-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-x) based on your clarifications. Your initial question was really unclear as to what error you were actually getting and what the chain of import statements is relative to the file structure. In future include an example that also has the relevant code you are running, how you are running the code, and the full traceback of the error you're getting.

Comment: Either put an empty `__init__.py` file in every directory including `somedir`, or make sure `dir1` is in your PYTHONPATH.

Comment: @Mihai exactly, that was the same problem as mine, that I failed to find out. I took the suggestion from *Vinod Rane*, that though worked, not quite satisfying. I've to figure out some nice one. Nonetheless, got at least one solution. Thanks for your cooperation.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose `dir1` is not on your python path. You can verify this by checking `sys.path` Try using relative imports in `b.py` [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)

Answer (score 0):

Your file might not running from the same directory as `dir1`. To check try `print(__file__)`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I got one working solution (not so satisfying though) as suggested from a link above by editing the `__init__.py` file as:

```
#__init__.py

import os
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), ".")))
```

Thanks everyone for their support.