# How can I implement a control function in my program and avoid the AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute error

Tags: python

I have a simlair problem as in this question: [AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250103/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute)

I'm doing a mutual top level import which is causing me to have AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute error so but I'm not sure if I can import within a function because I'm basically importing a file that controls all the other modules.

Here's an example(file2.py):

```
import file1
count = 0
while count < file1.number_of_loops:
 .....
```

My functions are being triggered by the control variables so I'm unable to import within the function itself.  Short of creating a sperate file to control, is there a way to refer to variables in another file without doing a mutual top level import?

Comment: pycharm seems to be a lot nicer than eclipse.

Comment: is this a problem with eclipse or how I am designing my program?

Comment: Sorry, why you can't import file1 from file2 functions? May be you've already red this [FAQ](http://docs.python.org/faq/programming.html#how-can-i-have-modules-that-mutually-import-each-other), I just leave it here :)

Comment: @Lostsoul: perhaps both. for pure parametric variables, approaches like using the ConfigParser module may be better design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by a comment, if you're using `file1.py` to store some configuration variables, then it would be better to have a look at alternative ways of dealing with that configuration.

In my opinion, a simple way to address your problem would be to move all those variables to another module called, for example, `settings.py` so that you can get the configuration from there without having to use any mutual import.

Answer (score 0):

I will advice **against an import from a module that controls *"all the other modules"***.

My suggestion is to put all that control code inside functions (or classes), and then import the functions and the paramenters where you need to execute them.

For example, `file2.py`:

```
def loop_control(num_loops):
    count = 0
    while count < num_loops:
        # ...
```

another file:

```
import file1
import file2

file2.loop_control(file.number_of_loops)
```

If you need to communicate back and forth the results of this controls you may consider building a Manager just for that (implemented in the way that you prefer).