# Consequences of shadowing built-in types/functions

Tags: python, built-in

I'm wondering what could be some consequences of reusing the names of built-in types or functions.
To illustrate what I mean, read the following example:

`list()` is a built-in function. 
If I create another `list()` method I suppose it will override the original one so that the mine will be executed instead of the built-in one. 
But what happen if i do `list=[a,z,e,r,t,y]`? Is there a risk for the built-in `list` type or `list()` function?

I know it's not good to do such a thing. But my goal is only to understand what could happen in these cases...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you will not damage the built-in `list` in any way. It will just [confuse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11141940/attributeerror-nt-stat-result-object-has-no-attribute-s-iwrite/11142152#11142152) everyone.

You can still get the original `list` via `__builtin__.list`. Assigning to `__builtin__.list` will, however, break `list` for everyone.