# sort list by frequency-value in python

Tags: python, sorting, count

im new to python and programming, and its not easy for me to get that stuff in my mind.
because the books i started to read are completely boring, i startet to play around with some ideas.

here is what i want to do:
open the textfile, count the frequency of every single value (just a list of systemnames), sort the list by frequency, and return the result.
after searching the web for some code to do it, i got this here:

```
file = open('C:\\Temp\\Test2.txt', 'r')
text = file.read()
file.close()


word_list = text.lower().split(None)

word_freq = {}

for word in word_list:

    word_freq[word] = word_freq.get(word, 0) + 1
list = sorted(word_freq.keys())
for word in list:
    print ("%-10s %d" % (word, word_freq[word]))
```

It works, but it sorts by the words / systemnames in the list:

```
pc05010    3
pc05012    1
pc05013    8
pc05014    2
```

I want it like that:

```
pc05013    8
pc05010    3
pc05014    2
pc05012    1
```

now im searching for the sort-by-value function for hours. i bet its so easy, but i found nothing.

for my beginners point of view, it has something to do with this line:

```
list = sorted(word_freq.keys())
```

i thought maybe its:

```
list = sorted(word_freq.values())
```

but no....
its very frustrating to me to see all the tons of information about this language, but could not get such simple things to work.

please help :)

thanks a lot!

Comment: You shouldn't use `list` as a variable name because it is the name of the built-in `list()` function. Doing so is called [shadowing builtins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11263502/consequences-of-shadowing-built-in-types-functions).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've to use `word_freq.items()` here:

```
lis = sorted(word_freq.items(), key = lambda x:x[1], reverse = True)
for word,freq in lis:
    print ("%-10s %d" % (word, freq))
```

Don't use `list` as a variable name.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at collections.Counter

```
>>> wordlist = ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'baz']
>>> import collections
>>> counter = collections.Counter(wordlist)
>>> counter.most_common()
[('foo', 2), ('baz', 1), ('bar', 1)]
```

Answer (score 4):

Use a [collections.Counter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to help with counting things, and [`with` statement](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm) to help with opening (and closing) files.

```
import collections

with open('C:\\Temp\\Test2.txt', 'r') as f:
    text = f.read()

word_freq = collections.Counter(text.lower().split())
for word, freq in word_freq.most_common():
    print ("%-10s %d" % (word, freq))
```

Comment: No problem - your answer was what I answered, so I just added the doc links.

Comment: wow, thank you very much. i will now try to understand collections thing with the links you added :)