# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'MibVariable'

Tags: pysnmp

I am exploring pysnmp (python snmp library). While executing an example, I got error

**AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'MibVariable'**

against method call **cmdgen.MibVariable('SNMPv2-MIB', 'sysDescr', 0)**

Example code is given below

```
from pysnmp.entity.rfc3413.oneliner import cmdgen
cmdGen = cmdgen.CommandGenerator()
errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = cmdGen.getCmd(
    cmdgen.CommunityData('public', 0),
    cmdgen.UdpTransportTarget(('demo.snmplabs.com', 161)),
    cmdgen.MibVariable('SNMPv2-MIB', 'sysDescr', 0),
    lookupNames=True, lookupValues=True
)
```

Normally, this happens if mutual top level imports exist as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250103/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute).

How can I overcome this issue without changing library source code?

Comment: Make sure you are using the latest pysnmp version. The MibVariable facility appeared in relatively recent pysnmp release.

Comment: I have pysnmp version 4.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need version 4.2.3 or greater. You can download it from here. I was getting a similar error and upgrading my version worked for me. 
http://sourceforge.net/projects/pysnmp/files/