# Python import nltk error

Tags: python, nltk, python-2.6

While importing nltk through terminal i got an error like this

```
[greenz@localhost hadoop]$ python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Feb 21 2013, 23:54:59) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import nltk
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/nltk/__init__.py", line 73, in <module>
    from internals import config_java
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/nltk/internals.py", line 10, in <module>
    import subprocess
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 425, in <module>
    import pickle
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/pickle.py", line 165, in <module>
    __all__.extend([x for x in dir() if re.match("[A-Z][A-Z0-9_]+$",x)])
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'match'
>>>
```

Any idea to resolve this?

Comment: Looks like the pickle module is broken. Try reinstalling python or, even better, upgrading to 2.7

Answer (score 2):

Could it be that you have an own file called 're.py' somewhere?

the re module has `re.match` by default, no way that this is missing.

You can find that out via `import re` and `print(re.__file__)`

Answer (score 1):

This Problem looks like of circular dependency. 
Take a look at this answer [attribution error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250103/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute). nltk has dependency on re module and for some reason re says that it needs to import nltk before getting fully loaded. re does not have an nltk dependency. I think this is happening because of some wrong re module coming in the python library path.

Try to import re directly in a new terminal and see where it is getting loaded from. you may have remove it and install the correct re module in the default location.

Answer (score -1):

Hi i just solved this problem by removing .pyc files from the directory in which my code is present.

Answer (score -1):

Upgrade your python from 2.6 to 2.7 or more and try again