# cyclic import AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute

Tags: python

I am trying to understanding cyclic import problem, Here I have three python files,

**py1.py**

```
import py3
py3.test3()
def test1():
    print 'test 1'
```

**py2.py**

```
import py1
py1.test1()
def test2():
    print 'test 2'
```

**py3.py**

```
import py2
py2.test2()
def test3():
    print 'test 2'
```

when I run the `python py3.py` and got the error like this,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "py3.py", line 1, in <module>
    import py2
  File "/home/me/Desktop/hackerearth/cylic/py2.py", line 1, in <module>
    import py1
  File "/home/me/Desktop/hackerearth/cylic/py1.py", line 1, in <module>
    import py3
  File "/home/me/Desktop/hackerearth/cylic/py3.py", line 3, in <module>
    py2.test2()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'test2'
```

But when I remove the `import py3` from py1.py file I got the output without any errors. Any one explain me why I am got this error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Python, files are executed *as* they are parsed. A function doesn't exist until its `def` has "executed".

Your problem is this: When you `import` a module, the parser stops where it's at in that file, and begins parsing (executing) the new file being imported.

So, when you run `python py3.py`, it begins parsing the file. It gets to `import py2`, then stops what it's doing to go start parsing `py2.py`, and so forth for `py1.py`.

When it gets to `import py3`, it *again* starts paring it. However, when it gets to `import py2`, it realizes it has *already* imported `py2`, and goes to the next line. Here, it encounters `py2.test2()`. However, remember that we never *finished* parsing `py2`, so `test2()` does not exist yet.

In order of execution:

```
# start at py3.py
import py2

# now in py2.py
import py1

# now in py1.py
import py3

# now in py3.py - this time being parsed as module
import py2       # this already happened, skip it.
py2.test2()      # doesn't exist yet
```

If you add `print` statements to the very top of your files, you will see this behavior.

---

The *real* problem is that you have global executable statements. If, instead, you include the typical construct:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # First real executable statement goes here
```

Then you'll never try to "do anything" before a module has fully imported.

Comment: Excellent explanation. So it is not related to circular import problem. Can you explain me `what is circular import problem in python ?`. I need to know about this.

Comment: This is the the circular input problem. It can be solved as I indicated at the end of my answer.

Comment: +1 for your good explanation..

Comment: Thank you. I encourage you to add `print "This is pyX.py"` at the top of all files and try it for yourself.

Comment: I tried as you said in the answer. your answer has good points. :)

Comment: Note that this solution is different form the accepted answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250103/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute