# Pygame AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'copy'

Tags: module, pygame, python-2.5, attributeerror, traceback

I encountered `Error: 'module' object has no attribute 'copy'` while running a pygame program. In my code, I never referred to a copy attribute, so I don't understand where the error is coming from.

Comment: have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250103/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute

Comment: Post the code to the program, along with the stacktrace. Use https://gist.github.com/ if it's a lot of code or stacktrace.

Comment: The link is https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9a529b53909ef8148bd4

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think there is a python file named "copy" in your directory. I had the same problem, after I delete the "copy" file, the error has gone.

Comment: Thank you for this very helpful tip!

Comment: Okay, this is genius finding. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I had the same problem and I deleted the file named wrongly as copy.py. But the error still persists, do you have any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Hey man, thank you soo much! I was trying to resolve that problem for couple of hours with no luck!