# ImportError: The 'pyparsing' package is required

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

> ImportError: The 'pyparsing' package is required; normally this is
> bundled with this package so if you get this warning, consult the
> packager of your distribution.

I can't seem to find the problem but when I searched it says to downgrade the `setuptools ==19.2` but it gives me an error in TensorFlow so anyone know a setuptools compatible version to work with `tensorflow==2.1.0`

```
pip version: 19.2

python: 3.7

Windows: 10
```

here is my pip list:

```
Package                Version
---------------------- -----------
absl-py                0.9.0
agents                 1.4.0
altgraph               0.17
astor                  0.8.1
astunparse             1.6.3
cachetools             4.1.0
certifi                2020.4.5.1
chardet                3.0.4
click                  7.1.2
cloudpickle            1.3.0
cycler                 0.10.0
dnspython              1.16.0
eventlet               0.25.2
Flask                  1.1.2
future                 0.18.2
gast                   0.2.2
google-auth            1.15.0
google-auth-oauthlib   0.4.1
google-pasta           0.2.0
greenlet               0.4.15
grpcio                 1.29.0
gym                    0.17.2
h5py                   2.10.0
idna                   2.9
importlib-metadata     1.6.0
itsdangerous           1.1.0
Jinja2                 2.11.2
joblib                 0.15.1
Keras-Applications     1.0.8
Keras-Preprocessing    1.1.2
kiwisolver             1.2.0
Markdown               3.2.2
MarkupSafe             1.1.1
matplotlib             3.2.1
monotonic              1.5
netifaces              0.10.6
numpy                  1.18.4
oauthlib               3.1.0
opencv-python          4.2.0.34
opt-einsum             3.2.1
packaging              20.4
pandas                 1.0.3
pefile                 2019.4.18
Pillow                 7.1.2
pip                    19.2
protobuf               3.12.0
pyasn1                 0.4.8
pyasn1-modules         0.2.8
pygame                 1.9.6
pyglet                 1.5.0
PyInstaller            3.6
pymongo                3.8.0
pyparsing              2.4.7
PySide2                5.12.3
python-dateutil        2.8.1
python-dotenv          0.13.0
python-engineio        3.13.0
python-socketio        4.6.0
pytz                   2020.1
pywin32-ctypes         0.2.0
PyYAML                 5.3.1
requests               2.23.0
requests-oauthlib      1.3.0
rsa                    4.0
ruamel.yaml            0.16.10
ruamel.yaml.clib       0.2.0
scikit-learn           0.23.1
scipy                  1.4.1
shiboken2              5.12.3
six                    1.14.0
sklearn                0.0
socketio               0.2.1
tensorboard            2.1.1
tensorboard-plugin-wit 1.6.0.post3
tensorflow-estimator   2.1.0
termcolor              1.1.0
threadpoolctl          2.0.0
tqdm                   4.46.0
urllib3                1.25.9
Werkzeug               1.0.1
wheel                  0.34.2
wrapt                  1.12.1
zipp                   3.1.0
```

Comment: are you trying to run the exe created by pyinstaller?

Comment: Create a virtual environment to avoid package version problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the `pyparsing` package you need to install `setuptools==19.2 or 20.0`

My tensorflow versions:

> gast-0.3.3 tensorboard-2.2.2 tensorflow-2.2.0 tensorflow-estimator-2.2.0
> pip: 20.1

just

`pip uninstall tensorflow`

then

`pip install tensorflow`

after doing this,I discovered a bug is that i named a file copy.py so it got confused:

`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23418949/pygame-attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-copy`

Thanks for all your help