# NoAlertPresentException when attempting to accept alert using SST Python

Tags: python, selenium

I'm attempting to accept a javascript alert that pops up when deleting an element on my webpage. When I use `accept_alert()` or `dismiss_alert()`, I'm receiving the `NoAlertPresentException: Message: u'no alert open\n` message. My code looks like this:

```
click_element(get_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="tracker"]/table[4]/tbody/tr/td[1]/a[1]'),wait=True)
accept_alert('Do you wish to delete?')
```

I have only been working with SST for 2 weeks, so I may be missing a simple solution.

The code that calls the javascript alert is as follows:

```
<a href="javascript: void(0);" onclick="return DeleteFood(1293652875);" class="track_remove" title="Remove">⊗</a>
```

Comment: Can you show the HTML code snippet of the element ?

Comment: Question updated with code that calls the javascript alert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call `click_element` with `wait=False` see [this](http://testutils.org/sst/actions.html#accept-alert)

So, something like the following should work

```
click_element(get_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="tracker"]/table[4]/tbody/tr/td[1]/a[1]'),wait=False)
accept_alert('Do you wish to delete?')
```

Comment: Still receiving the `NoAlertPresentException`.

Comment: I have taken a look at the APIs again and seems like SST doesn't require `switch to alert`. So two possible solutions can be passing both parameter `accept_alert` requires. such as `accept_alert(expected_text=None, text_to_write=None)` if you don't have to pass `text` or simply `accept_alert()`

Comment: the first `accept_alert(expected_text=None, text_to_write=None)` worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Please try below after clicking on element which opens alert

```
 try:
    WebDriverWait(browser, 3).until(EC.alert_is_present())

    alert = browser.switch_to_alert.accept()

    print "alert accepted"
except TimeoutException:
    print "no alert"
```

Comment: That brings up an `AssertionError: Could not identify element: 0 elements found`

Comment: Now receiving `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'TimeoutException'`. I did an `import selenium.common` to pull the exception. So, I'm not sure why I'm getting this. Is it because SST doesn't always play nice with selenium code?

Comment: I changed it to `alert = browser.switch_to_alert.accept()` and still receiving the `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'TimeouException'`

Comment: I think we  have to check the imports in the code. Please check below link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250103/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute

Comment: My imports are: `import unittest
from sst.actions import *
from sst import cases, config, browsers
import selenium.common`

Answer (score 0):

```
    try:
        ** your code **

    except Exception as e:
        try:
            self.driver.switch_to.alert.accept()
            print(e)
        except NoAlertPresentException as e:
            print(e)
```