# PyCharm returns error in from all files in project folder

Tags: python, pycharm

I have a whole project folder where Pycharm returns error whenever I try to run a file. If I run them from terminal they all work.

> /usr/bin/python /Users/Casper/PycharmProjects/Mayer/Mayer5.py
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 550, in 
>       main()
>     File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 532, in main
>       known_paths = addusersitepackages(known_paths)
>     File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 266, in addusersitepackages
>       user_site = getusersitepackages()
>     File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 241, in getusersitepackages
>       user_base = getuserbase() # this will also set USER_BASE
>     File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 230, in getuserbase
>       from sysconfig import get_config_var
>     File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 104, in 
>       _PROJECT_BASE = os.path.dirname(_safe_realpath(sys.executable))
>     File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 99, in _safe_realpath
>       return realpath(path)
>     File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 375, in realpath
>       path, ok = _joinrealpath('', filename, {})
>     File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 400, in _joinrealpath
>       if not islink(newpath):
>     File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 138, in islink
>       return stat.S_ISLNK(st.st_mode)
>   AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'S_ISLNK'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250103/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute), it can be two possible reasons:

1. **Circular dependencies:**

   If in the first `a.py` file you `import b` and in `b.py` you `import a`,then you might see this happen. Python will decide by itself which module will be load first.
2. **Module named in your `.py` is the same as one in Python standard files:**

   In this case you have to change your module name.

You need to provide more info about your codes so we can figure out which one is the root cause.

Comment: The project contains about 7 files and I even tried to make a new file with a very simple print "hello world" and I get the same error no matter what file in the folder I try to run

Comment: Can you list the file names in your project?

Comment: Mayer6.py, Mayer5.py, py4.py, stat.py, py.py, py2.py, py3.py

Comment: And I import the same libraries in the same order in the two first files

Comment: Rename `stat.py`, there is already a `stat.py` in Python standard lib.

Comment: If you think my answer helps, please upvote it, thanks!