# AttributeError: Why does the module first imported not register as an attribute?

Tags: python

i.e the first module I try to import does not work but the others work. I know it's a problem with the module in the first position because I switched them and each time, when in the first position I get an `AttributeError` saying that the 'module' object has no attribute ' '. 
Here's an example of how I import them:

```
from os import name, system #Note, this import comes before the other three below.
import product as p #The module in this position returns an attribute error
import rewards as r
import sale as s
```

I also tried importing them this way but the module first imported still does not work:

```
import product as p, rewards as r, sale as s
```

Comment: The code you posted does not appear capable of generating the error you report.  I suspect that something's going wrong with an import inside of one of your modules - perhaps something that they all import, so that whichever one you import first triggers the failure.  The FULL error traceback (not just an excerpt from it) may give a hint as to the location of the actual problem.

Comment: @jasonharper It's not the code because in a full block (all functions in one file) it runs perfectly fine. The `main` module (where I am trying to import the modules to) however does return a `Refactor` message of `Too many statements` in the `main` module. Could it be that?

Answer (score 0):

[AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250103/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute)
<<<-This link answered my question. I discovered I had mutual top-level imports in the modules I was trying to import in the main module. Because of this I got an AttributeError like in the link.