# Importing main.py into another module (contained in the same directory)

Tags: python, python-2.7, webapp2

How do I import a class from `main.py` into another file in the same directory?

**File structure:**

```
Project
    |-- main.py
    |-- first_file.py
    |-- second_file.py
```

**main.py**:

```
class ClassX():
    def random1(self):
        ....
        return stuff

    def get(self):
        class_x_stuff = self.random1()
        print class_x_stuff

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/classw', ClassW),
    ('/classx', ClassX)
], debug=True)
```

**first_file.py**:

```
import main

checkpoint = main.ClassX()
print checkout
```

**Output:**

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ClassX'
```

Resources I've used:

1. [How to import the class within the same directory or sub directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142151/how-to-import-the-class-within-the-same-directory-or-sub-directory)
2. [AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250103/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute)

I'm able to import the `first_file.py` into `main.py` as well as into `second_file.py`. But I am unable to import `main.py` into the other files.

Renaming the `main.py` file, (for example, `proj_main.py`) results in an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
  handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
File "/usr/local/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler
  handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
File "/usr/local/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject
  obj = __import__(path[0])

ImportError: No module named main
```

*What are my options? How can I resolve this issue?*

**EDIT:**

Full Traceback:

```
INFO     2017-10-02 22:10:21,744 dispatcher.py:226] Starting module "default" running at: http://localhost:7070
INFO     2017-10-02 22:10:21,747 admin_server.py:116] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
ERROR    2017-10-02 22:10:24,017 wsgi.py:263] 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/usr/local/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler
handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "/usr/local/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject
obj = __import__(path[0])
  File "/Users/mycomputer/Documents/project_folder/main.py", line 34, in <module>
from first_file import ClassY
  File "/Users/mycomputer/Documents/project_folder/first_file.py", line 20, in <module>
    checkpoint = main.ClassX()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute ‘ClassX’
INFO     2017-10-02 22:10:24,023 module.py:832] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Comment: How does `first_file.py` get executed (when you get the `AttributeError`)?

Comment: `Class ClassX():` -> `class ClassX:`: lower case _c_ and (optionally) no braces.

Comment: That was actually just an error in typing but in my code it is lowercase: `class` so the issue isn't that.

Comment: @martineau `first_file.py` isn't running at all. When I run the application in localhost the result is: `This page isn’t working 127.0.0.1 is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500`

Comment: In that case please [edit] your question again and add the full traceback that appears before the `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ClassX'` exception.

Comment: @martineau I added the full traceback and realized I have circular dependency. I am able to fix it now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that I was experiencing [circular dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250103/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute):

```
File "/Users/mycomputer/Documents/project_folder/main.py", line 34, in <module>
from first_file import ClassY
```

*Note that `main.py` was importing from `first_file` and then `first_file` was importing from `main.py` which caused a [circular import gotcha](http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm#circular-imports).*

**Solution:**

**first_file.py**

```
import second_file

checkpoint = second_file.class_x()
    print checkout
```

**second_file.py**

```
import main

def class_x():
    item = main.ClassX()
    return item
```