# Why does python script throw AttributeError: 'module' object not found, but works when made executable?

Tags: python, linux

I have read through already answered similar questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250103/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute#1250135).
I have been facing similar issue in my modules. However, when I make the python script executable with `chmod` and copy it to `/usr/local/bin`, I can run the script by calling its name.
What changes when I make it executable? Why doesn't it work otherwise?

Comment: add path to .bashrc file

Comment: I did not add anything to .bashrc, but the error vanishes after I make it executable. What exactly is the change?

Comment: if you add below line to .bashrc you can run your code from anywhere in terminal

Comment: I don't want to do that. Please read my question again.

Comment: when you make it executable then you can access that script as application also.

Comment: Yes I know. But why doesn't it throw the error after I make it executable? It only throws error when I run it with `python`

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

My python script was compatible with python 3, but not python 2. When I ran with python 2 (i.e. by command `python`), it throws AttributeError.
The script works when made executable because of `#!/usr/bin/env python3` in my script, telling the shell which interpreter to use.