# E ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'snowflake.connector'; 'snowflake' is not a package" in Pycharm while running pytest script

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

i am getting "E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'snowflake.connector'; 'snowflake' is not a package" error when try to run pytest scripts in pycharm. I have done pip install snowflake but still i get the error. Can anyone help on this issue

Can anyone suggest what can be the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use below command

```
pip install snowflake-connector-python
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. But next ends up in Fixture Not Found Error: Though the fixture is present. Any idea why keep getting this issue?

E       fixture 'load_clinops_tables' not found
>       available fixtures: batchId, cache, capfd, capfdbinary, caplog, capsys, capsysbinary, connection, doctest_namespace, extra, host, include_metada
ta_in_junit_xml, lifecycle, metadata, monkeypatch, pytestconfig, record_property, 
path, tmp_path_factory, tmpdir, tmpdir_factory
>       use 'pytest --fixtures [testpath]' for help on them.

Comment: Can u please post your code, this seems to be issue with pytest not with snowflake library. Also please accept the answer if your issue was resolved.

Comment: def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    tenant = metafunc.config.option.tenant
    host = metafunc.config.option.host                                                                                     if 'load_clinops_tables' in metafunc.fixturenames:
            available_data = config_loader.Loader(tenant, host).provide_clinops_tables()
            metafunc.parametrize('load_clinops_tables', available_data)

Comment: can you log question about this issue, so that community will be able to help you

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue and tried this; it worked for me.
If you have installed both snowflake and snowflake-connector-python, just uninstalling the snowflake package will resolve the issue.

[Issue with using snowflake-connector-python with Python 3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62658847/issue-with-using-snowflake-connector-python-with-python-3-x/73949983#73949983)