# Can't use defined type in C Python extension

Tags: python, c++, python-c-api

I'm following the [C Python extension tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/newtypes_tutorial.html) to create new type.
I created the file `custom.c`, `setup.py` and added the following line to my `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
execute_process(WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR} COMMAND ${PYTHON_BIN} setup.py build)
```

But when I run

```
Py_Initialize();
PyImport_AddModule("custom"));
PyRun_SimpleString("import custom\nmycustom = custom.Custom()");
PyErr_Print();
```

I got `Attribute error: module 'custom' has no attribute 'Custom'` even if I add the path to generated .pyd to `sys.path`

Python help on module is

```
Help on module custom:

NAME
    custom

FILE
    (built-in)
```

I am running on Windows 10 with Python 3.8

But I can import and use the module directly from a Python terminal

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250103/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute) can help you

Comment: No it doesn't :/ Still got Attribute error

Comment: This is not very complete... (see [example]) You have to follow the instruction in that external link to recreate the error.

Comment: Perhaps check if the "current folder" that you build the program in doesn't happen to have a file named `custom.py`, or you don't have a package named `custom`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
PyImport_AddModule("custom"));
```

See https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/import.html#c.PyImport_AddModuleObject; this looks in `sys.modules` for "custom". If it can't find it then it creates a new empty module named "custom". It does not search the path for files.

```
import custom
```

This looks in `sys.modules` for "custom". If it finds a module there then it returns it. If it doesn't find a module then it searches the Python path for a suitable module.

You're programmatically creating a blank module, and that is getting used instead of the module on the Python path.