# How do I import a module within the same directory or subdirectory?

Tags: python, module, importerror

I have the following directory for a project:

```
photo_analyzer/
│
├── main.py                # Main script to run the photo analyzer
├── gui/                   # Directory for GUI-related files
│   ├── __init__.py        # Package initialization
│   ├── app.py             # Tkinter application class and main GUI logic
│   ├── widgets.py         # Custom Tkinter widgets (if needed)
│   ├── styles.py          # Styling configurations for the GUI
│   └── resources/         # Directory for GUI resources (e.g., icons, images)
│       ├── icon.png       # Application icon
│       └── ...
│
├── photo_analysis/        # Directory for photo analysis-related files
│   ├── __init__.py        # Package initialization
│   ├── photo_utils.py     # Utility functions for photo manipulation
│   ├── light_profiles.py  # Functions to analyze light profiles in photos
│   └── ...
```

I'm trying to import `photo_utils` and `light_profiles` from the `photo_analysis` module into `gui/app.py`. Whenever I try to run `app.py`, I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Josh\Documents\PhotoAnalyzer\gui\app.py", line 6, in <module>
    from photo_analysis import photo_utils
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'photo_analysis'
```

I have empty `__init__.py` files in both directories, so I don't think that's the issue. I've tried adding the `photo_analysis` module to the Python path using `SET PYTHONPATH="C:\Users\Josh\Documents\PhotoAnalyzer\photo_analysis"` and I've tried to use the `sys.path` technique as well. Both end with the same error message as before.

`photo_utils.py` imports `widgets.py` from the "gui" module. Could I be experiencing circular dependency? I did try the work-around explained in [text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250103/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute) by importing `widgets` into each method in `photo_utils` that used it, and while this allowed a test main code in `photo_utils` to run properly, `app.py` still gives the same error message that there is no module named 'photo_analysis'.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a tricky one. Normally python imports from their sibling files or childs of sibling folders.
Here if you want to import from a file that are from same parent then you have to use `sys.path.append('.')`

Secondly it also depends on the terminal current working directory. If your current working directory is "photo_analyzer" then adding these line will work

```
import sys
sys.path.append('.')
import photo_analysis.photo_utils as pa
```

Otherwise if your current working directory is "photo_analyzer/gui", then you have to add these lines

```
import sys
sys.path.append('./../photo_analysis')
import photo_utils as pa
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I actually had to end up appending the path to both photo_utils.py and app.py!

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to the `photo_analyzer/` directory and run

```bash
python3 -m gui.app
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error. Running the file in a command prompt is going to have the same outcome as running the main method in the actual python script.

Comment: interesting… I replicated your file structure on my machine and the above command worked for me. Hopefully someone can chime in with some insight about this discrepancy.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use relative imports.

In `gui/app.py`, you can use relative imports to import modules from the `photo_analysis` package.

```py
# gui/app.py

# Use relative import to import photo_utils from photo_analysis package
from ..photo_analysis import photo_utils

# Use relative import to import light_profiles from photo_analysis package
from ..photo_analysis import light_profiles
```

The .. in the import statement means to go up one level in the directory hierarchy, and then you can access the modules inside the photo_analysis package.

Also, make sure you are running `main.py` or another script from the root directory (`photo_analyzer/`) that imports `gui.app` or other modules. If you run `app.py` directly, it might not find the `photo_analysis` package.

This [guide](https://neuronalmindscapes.com/blog/2023/08/01/successfully-import-python-modules-from-directories-and-subdirectories-a-comprehensive-guide-with-code-snippets/) has a pretty good explanation of how relative imports work.